# VBScript - Date and Time Constraints for Running a File

Tags: datetime, audio, if-statement, vbscript, runtime-error

Ok I am new with writing VBScript and I want to write a string of code that plays a file (WAV format) only on a certain day and only between specific times. After piecing together multiple fragments of code I found on the internet I was left with the following:

```
Dim myDateString 
Dim thing1 
thing1 = 0 
myDateString = Date() 
If myDateString < "13/08/13" Then 
thing1 = 1 
end if 
if thing1 = 1 then  
If myDateString > "15/08/13" Then 
thing1 = 2 
end if  
end if

if thing1 = 2 then 

hournow = hour(Time())
If hour(Time()) >= 9 And Hour(Now()) < 22 Then

set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

music = "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\MYSOUND.wav"

WshShell.Run "wmplayer """ & music & """",0,True

Else     
wscript.quit 1 
End If

Else
wscript.quit 1
End If
```

Ok so I had set this for the date I ran this on, within the hour I was in. But
it didn't work. I expected the VBS to start playing MYSOUND.wav but it didn't. When running the file
there were no errors though, so I was wondering what I did wrong!

I running Windows 7

If anyone could tell me what I did wrong, and how to fix it that would be great.

Double points if anyone could post a corrected version of the code!

Thanks to any answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, indent your code and give your variables meaningful names!

Then, your date comparison doesn't work because you're trying to compare strings as if they were dates. This usually won't work (depending on your "system locale"): you need to use date type variables and an actual date comparison function (DateDiff in VBScript).

(EDIT: as Ansgar Wiechers pointed out, you don't need to use DateDiff to compare dates in VBScript, "DateStart <= Now And Now <= DateEnd" will do just fine)

Try this:

```
Dim DateStart, DateEnd, WshShell, music

DateStart = DateSerial(2013, 8, 13)
DateEnd = DateSerial(2013, 8, 15)
If DateDiff("D", DateStart, Now) >= 0 And DateDiff("D", Now, DateEnd) >= 0 Then
    If Hour(Now) >= 9 And Hour(Now) < 22 Then
        '*** delete after debugging ***
        MsgBox "play sound"
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        music = "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\MYSOUND.wav"
        '*** 2nd parameter : 0 hides wmplayer, 1 shows it ***
        WshShell.Run "wmplayer """ & music & """", 1, True
    Else
        '*** delete after debugging ***
        MsgBox "Not the right time"
    End If
Else
    '*** delete after debugging ***
    MsgBox "Not the right day"
End If
```

Also, if you want to debug a small script like this, you can call MsgBox to do a simple tracking of what's actually executed (in your example, replacing your "WScript.Quit 1" by MsgBox would show you that the date is not properly compared.

Comment: You're overcomplicating things. Dates can be compared just fine with normal comparison operators (`DateStart < Now`). No need for `DateDiff`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed my problem perfectly!
Just to be a pain, is there a way to wait until a specific time (On the right day) Before the script plays the sound file? If not, thank you for your effort so far!

I'd vote up your answer if I had enough reputation!